# How to initialize a constexpr std::array with templated constexpr member functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++17, constexpr

This is a follow up of my question [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664672/how-to-create-a-constexpr-array-with-a-sequence-of-string-views-at-compile-time). In the end I want to create a `constexpr std::array` containing text with an appended running index.

I wanted to try a different approach than in the previous question.

Nearly everything, what I do in the below code is constexpr. But maybe, it is simply the old problem of returning a pointer to a no longer existing variable. But, I doubt this.

Please see the following code, where the not working line in function main is marked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <string>

// Some example text
static constexpr const char BaseString[]{ "text" };

// To create something like "text123" as constexpr
template <const size_t numberToConvert, const char* Text>
class Converter {
public:
    // Some helper variables
    static constexpr size_t TextLength{ std::char_traits<char>::length(Text) };
    static constexpr size_t NumberOfDigits{ ([]() constexpr noexcept {size_t result = 0; int temp = numberToConvert; for (; temp != 0; temp /= 10) ++result; return result; }()) };
    static constexpr size_t ArrayLength{ (numberToConvert ? 1u : 2u) + NumberOfDigits + TextLength };

    // Here we will build the text
    char buf[ArrayLength]{};

    // Constructor: Convert number to character digits
    constexpr Converter() noexcept {
        size_t i{ 0 };  for (; i < TextLength; ++i) buf[i] = Text[i]; // Copy text
        if (numberToConvert == 0) buf[i] = '0';     
        else {
            i = NumberOfDigits + TextLength - 1;    // Convert number to character digits
            int number = numberToConvert; for (; number; number /= 10)
                buf[i--] = number % 10 + '0';
        }
    }
    // cast operator
    constexpr operator const char* () const noexcept { return buf; }
    // For test purposes
    constexpr const char* data() const noexcept { return buf; }
};

// Driver program
int main() {

    // Temporaray constexprs
    constexpr Converter<123, BaseString> conv123{};     // Default construction
    constexpr auto conv2 = Converter<2, BaseString>();  // Assign / copy

    // Build constexpr std::array and initialize it with constexprs
    constexpr std::array< const char*, 2> convArray1{ conv123, conv2 };
    // Show that it works
    std::copy(convArray1.begin(), convArray1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // Does compile, but not work. Array will be initialized with nullptr *******************************************
    constexpr std::array< const char*, 2> convArray2{ Converter<2, BaseString>(), Converter<2, BaseString>().data() };
    std::cout << convArray2[0] << '\n' << convArray2[0] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

So, I can create `constexpr` "values" with my templated class. Those values can be used in the "initializer" list for a `constexpr std::array`. But, if I want to use my class directly in the initializer list, then it compiles, but stores only nullptrs. Output of the program is:

```
text123
text2
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠<½7
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠<½7
```

---

**Why does this happen? Or, is there a solution?**

---

Compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2, C++17, Debug, X86

Comment: It doesn't compile with Clang or GCC, but it does compile with MSVC https://godbolt.org/z/737Eb4

Comment: Then it is obviously some MSVC extension that makes it compilable. What a tragedy.

Comment: `Array will be initialized with nullptr` why do you think that?  It looks like garbage pointers, not nill

Comment: I saw it somewhere using the debugger and going down into library code (in xutil and xstring). But this was maybe with some other code variant. But it could of course point to anywhere. Anyway, it does not work . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code generating compile time dangling pointers (which should be impossible) on MSVC.

To fix:

```
template <const size_t numberToConvert, const char* Text>
class Converter {
  // blah
  std::array<char, ArrayLength> buf{};
  constexpr operator std::array<char, ArrayLength>() const { return buf; }
  constexpr std::array<char, ArrayLength> get() const { return *this; }
};
```

and remove other conversion operators and `data` method.

```
template<const size_t numberToConvert, const char* Text>
constexpr auto Converted = Converter<numberToConvert, Text>{}.get();
```

and now use `Converted<blah...>.data()` to get the pointers you want.

If you really want implicit conversion to character pointer:

```
template<const size_t numberToConvert, const char* Text>
struct Convertest {
  constexpr operator char const*() const { return Converted<numberToConvert,Text>.data(); }
};
```

rename classes and variables however you like.

Comment: After fixing the bugs in your above example, it will compile on MSVC, Clang and gcc. And it works. Hard to understand why, I think the key was the usage of the templated variable. There was no chance to omit that. But with that, it works. I will give an additional answer to myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664672/how-to-create-a-constexpr-array-with-a-sequence-of-string-views-at-compile-time/65738300#65738300

Comment: @ArminMontigny Yes, `// blah` probably won't work.  ;)  What else did I mess up?

Comment: Sequence of template parameters in ````std::array```` and additionall brackets in the declaration of the "get" function. But really no problem. As said. It works perfectly. But I still do not understand, why the additional templated variable is mandatory and cannot be omitted. Anyway. Great answer. +1+accept

Comment: @ArminMontigny The templated variable provides (compile time and run time) storage for the array, so a pointer to it can be formed.  Pointers have to point to things.  You can do it other ways, but a simple template constexpr variable is the easiest I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
constexpr std::array< const char*, 2> convArray2{ Converter<2, BaseString>(), 
                                                  Converter<2, BaseString>().data() };
```

Here, you are storing pointers to temporary variables - both `Converter` objects seize to exist after `;`. Making dereferencing the pointers UB.

Clang rejects such code giving quite helpful message:

```
<source>:51:43: note: pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression
<source>:51:55: note: temporary created here
    constexpr std::array< const char*, 2> convArray2{ Converter<2, BaseString>(), Converter<2, BaseString>().data() };
                                                      ^
2 errors generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

I am not sure about the specific `constexpr` rules but the code is unsafe even if it would compile.

Comment: Yes, UB, I was assuming that and therefore mentioned it in my question. The MSVC compiled it somehow and gave me the impression that it somehow worked by using constexpr . . .

Answer (score 1):

In [Cpp-Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) you can see that

> A constant expression is either
> [...]
> a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints: [...] if the value is of pointer type, it holds - address of an object with static storage duration

So, for `convArray1`

```
constexpr std::array< const char*, 2> convArray1{ conv123, conv2 };
```

you have to make `static` `conv123` and `conv2`

```
// VVVVVV
   static constexpr Converter<123, BaseString> conv123{};
   static constexpr auto conv2 = Converter<2, BaseString>();
// ^^^^^^
```

because you can't have a constant expression from a pointer with not static storage.

For `convArray2`

```
constexpr std::array< const char*, 2> convArray2{ Converter<2, BaseString>(), Converter<2, BaseString>().data() };
```

I don't see a way to get a `constexpr` object from pointers inside temporary objects.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My approach will not work. So, I will continue to looked for the next approach . . .