# Building GCC SIMD vector constants using constexpr functions (rather than literals)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, simd, constexpr

I'm writing a piece of code using [GCC's vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) (`__attribute__((vector_size(x)))`) that needs several constant masks. These masks are simple enough to fill in sequentially, but adding them as vector literals is tedious and error prone, not to mention limiting potential changes in vector size.

Is it possible to generate the constants using a constexpr function?

I've tried generating the values like this:

```
using u8v = uint8_t __attribute__((vector_size(64)));

auto generate_mask = []() constexpr {
    u8v ret;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(u8v); ++i) {
        ret[i] = i & 0xff;
    }
    return ret;
};
constexpr auto mask = generate_mask();
```

but GCC says modification of `u8v` is not a constant expression.

Is there some workaround, using G++ with C++20 features?

Comment: Please don't leave out the includes/typedefs when you post code snippets...

Comment: You could create a std::array with your technique, then have a function that uses integer_sequence to initialize a vector from the content of the array.

Comment: Also, I think it would be a good idea to file an enhancement request with both gcc and clang to allow such code.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically possible, but complicated to the point of being unusable. [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673188/126995) unrelated to SIMD.

Still, the workarounds aren’t that bad.

SIMD vectors can’t be embedded into instruction stream anyway. Doesn’t matter your code says `constexpr auto mask`, in reality the compiler will generate the complete vector, place the data in the read-only segment of your binary, and load from there as needed.

The exception is when your vector can be generated faster than RAM loads. A vector with all zeroes can be made without RAM access with `vpxor`, a vector with all bits set can be made with `vpcmpeqd`, and vectors with the same value in all lanes can be made with broadcast instructions. Anything else will result in full-vector load from the binary.

This means you can replace your `constexpr` with `const` and the binary will be the same. If that code is in a header file, ideally you’d also want `__declspec(selectany)` when building with VC++, or in your case the GCC’s equivalent is `__attribute__((weak))`